# WCF: Switched computers, now bidirectional serialization has stopped working

Tags: wcf, generated-code

I'm using [this](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) code generator to create business objects, with bidirectional serialization attributes, that can be sent from a server to a client using WCF. This used to work, but I've switched computers, and now I seem to only have unidirectional serialization, even though the source code has not changed.

This is a property that I would expect to still be serialized:

```
partial void OnApplicationIDChanging(int value);
partial void OnApplicationIDChanged();
private int _ApplicationID;
[Column(Storage=@"_ApplicationID", DbType=@"Int NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
[DataMember(Order=2)]
public int ApplicationID
{
    get { return _ApplicationID; }
    set {
        if (_ApplicationID != value) {
            if (_Application.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue) {
                throw new ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
            }
            OnApplicationIDChanging(value);
            SendPropertyChanging();
            _ApplicationID = value;
            SendPropertyChanged("ApplicationID");
            OnApplicationIDChanged();
        }
    }
}

private EntityRef<Application> _Application;
[Association(Name=@"Application_ApplicationExecution", Storage=@"_Application", ThisKey=@"ApplicationID", OtherKey=@"ApplicationID", IsForeignKey=true)]
public Application Application
{
    get {
        return _Application.Entity;
    }
    set {
        Application previousValue = _Application.Entity;
        if ((previousValue != value) || (!_Application.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)) {
            SendPropertyChanging();
            if (previousValue != null) {
                _Application.Entity = null;
                previousValue.ApplicationExecutions.Remove(this);
            }
            _Application.Entity = value;
            if (value != null) {
                value.ApplicationExecutions.Add(this);
                _ApplicationID = value.ApplicationID;
            }
            else {
                _ApplicationID = default(int);
            }
            SendPropertyChanged("Application");
        }
    }
}
```

That property is on a class called ApplicationExecution. When I pull that object down, its Application property is populated on the server side, but it is null when I try to access it on the client side, after it is retrieved via a WCF service call.

I'm pretty sure all of the correct attributes are still there. Am I missing anything? If not, what might have caused this to stop working?

Comment: Did you check fs the server blocking this communication, firewall?  Also did you check for any interesting items in the server's Event Viewer?  And client's event log?